# Load test resources within other module?

Tags: java, maven, junit

I'm using a abstract class in another module for reading and input for my testdata with:

```
package src/main/java/path/to/my/base/testclass;
InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

`filename` is eg `"test.txt"`, located in `src/main/resources/path/to/my/base/testclass`

As long as I put this abstract class into the same module as my testclasses are in, everything works fine.
Then i extract the acstract class (as well as the resources) to other module, compile, add to pom etc.
Result: My test implementation runs fine, but: I'm getting IO exception as the `file could not be found.`

What am I missing here? Why does the abstract class work within the same module, but not within another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test resources are for this artifact's tests only, they don't get deployed.

There are two possible ways around this:

- Dirty: Make your app [deploy a test jar along with the main jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html#How_to_create_a_jar_containing_test_classes),
  and add that as a dependency with scope TEST to the second artifact.
- Clean: Create a separate test artifact for base test classes and
  common test resources. Important: in this artifact, nothing goes in src/test and everything goes in src/main. Reference this test artifact from both other
  artifacts with scope TEST.

Comment: Hm I thought this is what I have? I placed the BaseClass in src/main, not in src/test. Then i referenced it in the pom of the new test module.

Comment: @membersound hmm. what you are doing is ugly as hell but should usually work. Wait: I hope you are referencing the file as `BaseClass.class.getResourceAsStream(filename)` !

Comment: I managed get it working by: `InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path/to/base/class/" + filename);` why is this ugly? I need a base class providing a test resource. I then have to use this base class to import the testfiles, and execute the files against different ITests contained in different artifact modules. Having a base abstract file importer base class is the only thing that works if I want to have the resources global in a central place, and not copied in every single module. Or could you suggest better? tnx

Comment: It's ugly because it means that your test class (or base class) gets deployed with your production code.